# CSS: Can you insert a selector into a predefined chain?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using a third party library that comes packaged with some CSS. I'd like to apply the rules for their selector to one of my own. My implementation has an unavoidable div blocking the chain. Is this possible?

For Example:

```
// Third party library definition
.class1 .class2 .class3 {
  // Some rules
}

// My custom chain
.class1 .class2 div .class3 {
  // ?
}
```

I do have access to SASS for this question.

Tried using SASS extensions

```
// Third party library definition
.class1 .class2 .class3 {
  // Some rules
}

// My custom chain
.class1 .class2 div .class3 {
 @extend class1;
}
```

Comment: even if you have the extra div both selector should select the same element so you don't have to do anything

Comment: Did you try it? Did it not work? Post a [mcve] please

Comment: It would be helpful to see a HTML code sample as well to determin why or why not the generated css will work.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, but you can just add your rule after the 3rd party rules.  Your rule has more selectors, which is more specific than their rule, so it should take precedence.  Plus, if you insert your rule **after** their rule, that's the "cascading" part of CSS, it will take precedence for this reason as well.

See my below example

```css
/*Third party library definition*/
.class1 .class2 .class3 {
  color: green;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

/*My custom chain*/
.class1 .class2 div .class3 {
  color: red;
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div>
      <p class="class3">Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```